# Are there any potential pitfalls in using the @ character for a key in an associative array in bash?

Tags: bash, special-characters, associative-array, key-value

I'm writing a bash script where I'm automating the creation of some basic test input files.

Because of the way the data is structured, there's a part in my script where I'd like to use the `@` character in some of the keys in an associative array.

From a cursory echo test, there doesn't seem to be any issues:

```
$ declare -A arr
$ arr[1]=hello
$ arr[2]=world
$ arr[@1]=foo
$ arr[@2]=bar
$ for var in "${!arr[@]}"; do echo "key: ${var}, value: ${arr[$var]}" ; done
key: @1, value: foo
key: 1, value: hello
key: @2, value: bar
key: 2, value: world
```

But since `@` is a [special character](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#APPREF), I'm wondering if this sort of key assignment is safe, and if not, what I could do to make it safer?

Comment: Unless you add the $ character in front of it, like any literal character, I guess no. The danger would just be the same as other characters. @ is also just special if used alone, besides being another in special patterns (`@()`) but I don't think it would apply with the assignment. Besides when expanding you could just quote it. And most of the time having the format `arr["key"]=value` is preffered.

Comment: Besides, if you ever get to face any problems using these *special* characters, you may simply surround them with single quotes `'<chars>'`, to prevent parameter expansion.

Comment: Thanks all. I didn't know that the quoted syntax was preferred; I'll do that to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), there is no problem for using `@` as a part of keyname for an *associative array*.

Bash use *at* `@` and *underscore* `_` as *alphanumeric* when converting to base64, in the following order:

> `0..9 a..z A..Z @ _`

```
$ echo {0..9} {a..z} {A..Z} @ _
```

Try this:

```
$ echo $((64#10))
64
$ echo $((64#_))
63
$ echo $((64#@))
62
$ echo $((64#Z))
61
$ echo $((64#A))
36
$ echo $((64#z))
35
$ echo $((64#a))
10
```

So under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), this could be ok.

#### Remark

But warn: If your script become an **application**, [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) could be a *not so good* choice for a development language.